# Variable Assignments in Python

Tags: python, list, variables, dictionary

I'm new to programming and python, and I'm looking for the best way to store information in my program.

I'm looking to store multiple values for each item, but don't know what the best way might be for this. It would be something like:

number: x position, y position, color

The problem I have is that I may have 1,000,000 numbers... Do I make a million dictionaries? And if I do, would I efficiently be able to call on all of them?

Comment: How are you learning Python? In general, the best way to store a million numbers is in a list. This site is for more specific questions you can't find by searching. I recommend watching some online tutorials. I personally found thenewboston.com very helpful when learning Python.

Comment: I've been teaching myself off of many different videos and articles over the last week or so. After some research I just wasn't sure if I could have one dictionary with each item having several values, or if I can even get away with doing that many dictionaries. Thanks for the replies though, it will definitely help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 types of arrays in Python. `list()` and `tuple()`. The former is mutable, whilst the latter is immutable. For the purpose of this work, you can assume that `list()` may later be modified, whilst `tuple()` may not.

To be honest, 100k data is not that much to handle by Python. A simple ordinary differential equation would produce more than that!

So, you can do it like this:

Store your individual arguments in tuples, so as to ensure (a) data integrity, and (b) memory optimisation.

```
var = (35, 56, (123,23,213))
```

Then add your `var` to a list containing all your data.

```
data_container = list() 
data_container.append(var)
```

`.append(var)`, however, is not the most efficient way to do it; for every time you append your data, you force a copy of the entire data in the RAM. A better way would be to initialise your `list` beforehand, then insert your data to it later on. Though for this, you need to know how much data input your will receive, or at least be willing to set a maximum!

This works as follows:

```
data_container = [[]]*int(1e5) # A list of 100,000 rows.
```

Following which, you may use a function to add to this list. This is a simplistic example. Although I'm passing a single numeric value, you can have anything you want. Don't forget to create a back door to break out of the loop! In this instance, the back door is a the value of input not being numeric (i.e. be a string, or just empty). Also, I am not handling the maximum inputs in here, nor am I using any conditions. Once you reach the maximum number of rows, you will end up with an `IndexError`. You can either handle this error and display a "maximum reached" message, or increase the capacity of your list by concatenating it to another list with extra rows. Your choice!

```
data_container = [[]]*int(1e1)
max_capacity = len(data_container)
ind = 0

def add2container(index, data):
    data_container[index] = data
    index += 1
    return index


while True:
    x = input('Enter x: ')
    if a.isnumeric():  # A Python 3 feature. 
        ind = add2container(ind, float(x))
    else:
        break
```

I hope this answers your question. But if not, please go ahead and ask / explain further.